# Casting objects in a way that we cast Primitive Data Types

Tags: java

I have three classes: `A`, `AA` and Top. A and AA extend Top.

Why is it that this won't compile:

```
A a = new A();
AA aa = (AA)a;
```

but this will:

```
float f = 4.3f;
int i = (int) f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Class `A` and class `AA` are on the same hierarchy, but they are side by side, so they can not be cast as one another.

Lets say class `A` was defined as so:

```
public class A extends Top{

   public A() {

   }

   public void foo(int i) {
      System.out.println(i);
   }

}
```

And that class `AA` was defined as so:

```
public class AA extends Top {

   public AA() {

   }

   public void bar(String s) {

   }

}
```

Now lets *theoretically* imagine what would actually happen if you tried to cast an `A` to an `AA` and it worked:

```
A a = new A();
(AA) aa = (AA) a;
```

Since `aa` has a **static type** of `AA`, Java would let you write code like this:

```
aa.bar("hi!");
```

Because the `AA` class has a bar method, BUT `aa` has a **dynamic type** of `A`, which means that the actual object that the variable `aa` refers to *does not* have a method called `bar("hi!")`.

(The **static type** of an object tells you what methods you can call on it and the **dynamic type** tells you what methods it actually has.)

So Java would tell `aa` to do `bar("hi!")` but `aa` wouldn't know what to do, because `aa` does not have the `bar` method defined.

Answer (score 0):

You may create cast method in the class you want to cast. Here I have cast type into type A by using a.cast(B b) method.

```
public class A {
    public int i;
    public  A cast(B b){
        A a = new A();
        a.i=b.i;
        return a ;
     }
}

public class B {
    public int i=10;
}



public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        A a= new A();
        a=a.cast(b);
        System.out.println(a.i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is a strong-type programming language, which means to define every variable, you need to specify its type, and for each variable, it can only hold a value belongs to the same type. For primitive types Java also defines the rules how different types can be casted to each other, there's `Widening Primitive Conversion`(no info loss) and `Narrowing Primitive Conversion`(info may loss), you can find more details at [the official Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2). So the reason you can do `int i = (int) f;` is that the conversion rule is defined in Java Spec and Java compiler **allows** you to do so. You can't do `int a = (int) true` if you tried, because there's no such a rule to convert `boolean` type to `int`.

Type casting rules for reference types are also simple, the compiler only allow you to do type casting `A a = (A) b` when it thinks the type of `b` **maybe** `A` or some `sub-type` of `A` in the type hierarchy, take a look at the following code:

```
Object b = c;
A a = (A) b;
```

compiler only knows that b is type `Object` but has no idea of its specific type, because `Object` is the `root` of Java type hierarchy, so the real type of `b` maybe any type, like type `A`, so the compiler will allow you to do so. If `b` actually is **not** a `A`, the error can only be found at runtime, when a `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

On the other hand, the compiler will prevent you to do `A a = (A) b` when it **clearly knows** that `b` is not type `A`:

```
class A {}
class B {}
```

If you have the above definition of type `A` and `B`, then compiler has enough information that an instance `B` is absolutely not type `A`, so it will give you a compile error of `Inconvertible types` when you try to do `A a = (A) new B()`. And this is one of big benefits to use a strong-type programming language: to guarantee type safety (at compile time for Java).